# scroll to top even with a ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

i have read all the stackoverflow solutions but it didnt work.

i have some divs and when i click on them it should change and load different data from server via ajax.
but whenever i click on it the page scroll to top.
i have tried "return false" and preventDefault .
here is my code:

```
$('.part').click(function(e) {
    var _this = $(this);
    if ($(this).attr('data-selected') == "") {
        _this.html('');
        var id = 76;
        $.post('banners/bannerjs.php', {
            'id': id
        }, function(result) {
            $(_this).append(result);
            $(_this).attr('data-selected', 'selected');

        });
    } else if ($(this).attr('data-selected') == "selected") {
        alert('salam');
    }
    return false;
});
```

and here is my html code:

```
<div class="part type<?php echo $w['TypeID']?>" style="" data-price="<?php echo $w['Price']?>" data-id="<?php echo $w['id']?>"
              data-selected="<?php echo $selected?>" data-banner-selected="<?php echo $w['Display_Banner_Selected']?>"
              data-banner="<?php echo $w['Display_Banner']?>">
              <script type="text/javascript">
              //jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
                if($('[data-id="<?php echo $w['id']?>"]').attr('data-selected') == "selected"){
                  var id = <?php echo $w['Display_Banner_Selected']?>;
                }else{
                var id = <?php echo $w['Display_Banner']?>;
              }
                $.post('banners/bannerjs.php', {'id': id}, function(result) {
                  $('[data-id="<?php echo $w['id']?>"]').append(result);
                });
                $('.<?php echo $banner['name'].$banner['id']?>').append('<div class="partPrice"><?php echo $w["Price"]?></div>');

              </script>

            <br>
          </div>
```

Comment: Please include the html element in your code that you are clicking on.

Comment: done ...........

Comment: If data-selected is not defined, your code won't do anything, fyi

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $(".part").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //this disables the default behavior of the element
      var _this = $(this);
      if ($(this).attr('data-selected') == "") {
          _this.html('');
          var id = 76;
          $.post('testy.php', {
              'id': id
          }, function(result) {
              $(_this).append(result);
              $(_this).attr('data-selected', 'selected');

          });
      } else if ($(this).attr('data-selected') == "selected") {
          alert('salam');
      }
      return false;
  });
})
</script>
<a class="part" data-selected="">Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false after your post:

```
$('.part').click(function(e) {
    var _this = $(this);
    if ($(this).attr('data-selected') == "") {
        _this.html('');
        var id = 76;
        $.post('banners/bannerjs.php', {
            'id': id
        }, function(result) {
            $(_this).append(result);
            $(_this).attr('data-selected', 'selected');
            return false; //added this
        });
    } else if ($(this).attr('data-selected') == "selected") {
        alert('salam');
        return false; //added this
    }
    return false;
});
```